# Extract specific XML tags Values in python

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file which contains tags like these.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DataFlows>
    <DataFlow id="ABC">
            <Flow name="flow4" type="Ingest">
                <Ingest dataSourceName="type1" tableName="table1">
                    <DataSet>
                        <DataSetRef>value1-${d1}-${t1}</DataSetRef>
                        <DataStore>ingest</DataStore>
                    </DataSet>
                    <Mode>Overwrite</Mode>
                </Ingest>
            </Flow>    
        </DataFlow>
        <DataFlow id="MHH" dependsOn="ABC">
            <Flow name="flow5" type="Reconcile">
                <Reconciliation>
                    <Source>QW</Source>
                    <Target>EF</Target>
                    <ComparisonKey>
                        <Column>dealNumber</Column>
                    </ComparisonKey>
    <ReconcileColumns mode="required">
                        <Column>bookId</Column>
                    </ReconcileColumns>
                </Reconciliation>
            </Flow>
            <Flow name="output" type="Export" format="Native">
                <Table publishToSQLServer="true">
                    <DataSet>
                        <DataSetRef>value4_${cob}_${ts}</DataSetRef>
                        <DataStore>recon</DataStore>
                        <Date>${run_date}</Date>
                    </DataSet>
                    <Mode>Overwrite</Mode>
                </Table>
            </Flow>
        </DataFlow>
</DataFlows>
```

I want to process this XML in python using Python Minimal DOM implementation.
 I need to extract information in DataSet Tag only when the Flow type in “Reconcile".

For Example:

If my Flow Type is "Reconcile" then i need to go to next Flow tag named "output" and extract values of DataSetRef,DataSource and Date tags.

So far i have tried below mentioned Code but i am getting blank values in all may fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom.minidom import parse

import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser

DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("Store.xml")

collection = DOMTree.documentElement

#if collection.hasAttribute("DataFlows"):

#   print "Root element : %s" % collection.getAttribute("DataFlows")

pretty = DOMTree.toprettyxml()

print "Collectio: %s" % collection

dataflows = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName("DataFlow")

# Print detail of each movie.

for dataflow in dataflows:

   print "*****dataflow*****"

   if dataflow.hasAttribute("dependsOn"):

      print "Depends On is present"

      flows = DOMTree.getElementsByTagName("Flow")

      print "flows"

      for flow in flows:

        print "******flow******"

        if flow.hasAttribute("type") and flow.getAttribute("type") == "Reconcile":

          flowByReconcileType = flow.getAttribute("type")

          TagValue = flow.getElementsByTagName("DataSet")

          print "Tag Value is %s" % TagValue

          print "flow type is: %s" % flowByReconcileType
```

From there onwards i need to  pass these 3  values extracted above  to Unix Shell scripts to process some directories.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, shows us what you tried so far.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I have updated my Code in question. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @rahulgulati Please edit your question to include your attempted code

Comment: @har07 I have updated it just now. Thanks for looking into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check if your XML is well formatted. You are missing a root tag and you got wrong double quotes for example here `<Flow name=“flow4" type="Ingest">`

IN your code you are correctly grabbing the dataflows.

You don't need to query the DOMTree again for the flows, you can check every dataflow's flow by querying like this:

```
flows = dataflow.getElementsByTagName("Flow")
```

Your condition `if flow.hasAttribute("type") and flow.getAttribute("type") == "Reconcile":` looks ok to me, so in order to get the next flow item you can do something like this always checking your index is inside the array.

```
for index, flow in enumerate(flows):
    if flow.hasAttribute("type") and flow.getAttribute("type") == "Reconcile":
        if index + 1 < len(flows):
            your_flow = flows[index + 1]
```

Comment: I have updated the XML in the question itself. And Thanks for the Answer.